# Bootstrap "ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I keep getting error messages in lighttable saying

"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: file:///Users/boricketts/Desktop/PortfolioWebsite/css/bootstrap.min.css"

I have downloaded bootstrap, and put the bootstrap folder into my websites folder on my desktop but it seems to not be working.

Comment: Does the file `file:///Users/boricketts/Desktop/PortfolioWebsite/css/bootstrap.min.css` exist?

Comment: the bootstrap folder usually has a dist>css folder, no?

Comment: You need to go look at the directory on your computer and see what it looks like. Does it have a css/bootstrap.min.css in it?

Answer (score 2):

If the bootstrap.min.css file is already in the website folder you should prefer to use a relative link like `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` instead of providing the full path.